# Drupal 7 - Render view after views_get_view_result

Tags: drupal-7

How do I render the view result that I get by calling "views_get_view_result"

So right now I have:

```
$variables['result'] = views_get_view_result('name', 'name-block');
```

And it returns an array of Object, which is what I want. Just can't figure out how to render it. Trying to render $result[0], $result[1] for example.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

For a simple way of doing this, use

`print views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_id');`

which is a utility function for doing what you want to do. See https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

Here is a thread with additional ways of doing this, if you need the extra complexity / depth. https://drupal.org/node/951442